# save and load images to localstorage

Tags: android

I try to save, for caching propose, few images to local storage.

The save part is done like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = ImagesHelper.loadBitmap(url, 3);  //here the image is downloaded from web
String fname = item.getItemID() + ".png";  //item is my object
if(fname != null){
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fname, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this method works, no exception is thrown. 
Now the not working part is cumming, the load image from local storage:

```
String fname = item.getItemID() + ".png";  //item is my object
if(file.exists()){
    try {
        Bitmap cacheImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        return cacheImg;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Error loading cache image", ex);
    }
}
```

This code always gets exception - the file exists, but the image cannot be loaded.

**Where is the error? Is this the correct way to save/load files to local storage?**

Comment: Where you have initialized `file`?Can you post that initialization code also?

Comment: the file.exists() returns true. The error is in Bitmap loader.

Comment: Well if `file.exists()` returns true, it doesn't mean that it is pointing to proper file. Second time when you initialize file `file` it might have created a new empty file in different directory right?That's why check if the directory is proper